# Changing a character in between patterns in vi/sed

Tags: sed, replace, wildcard, vi

I am struggling to work out how to get a , out from inbetween various patterns such as:
`500,000
xyz ,CA`

I have tried something like:

```
sed -E "s/\([a-zA-Z]*\),([a-zA-Z]*\)/\([a-zA-Z]*\) ([a-zA-Z]*\)/g" $file -i
```

It picks up the first pattern, but then over writes it with the second pattern, I feel like I am missing something very simple and I can't work it out, any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the notion of capture groups, I think. To refer to a parenthesized portion of the search within the replacement string, use `\1` for the first group, `\2` for the second group, etc.

The modified line would be:

```
sed -E "s/([a-zA-Z]),([a-zA-Z])/\1 \2/g" $file -i
```

Rather than replacing the part that matches the first `([a-zA-Z])` with the literal text "`([a-zA-Z])`", this modified line just copies the matched portion into the output (and likewise for the second group).

Comment: Got you, I totally wasn't getting that!  What you said works, am applying for the various patterns I have to work on.